# How do I grab an external variable after the external file has been executed?

Tags: php, variables

I'm trying to grab a variable from an external file, but I need the file to execute first. How can I do that?

I need to grab the variables: `$title`, `$description`, `$link`, `$date`, and `$author`.

rss.php:

```
$rss2_file = 'http://www.rune-pk.org/forums/external.php?forumids=2&type=rss2';


$is_item = false;
$tag = '';
$title = '';
$description = '';
$link = '';
$date = '';
$author = '';

function character_data($parser, $data) {
    global $is_item, $tag, $title, $description, $link, $date, $author;
    if ($is_item) {
        switch ($tag) {
            case "TITLE":
                $title .= $data;
                break;

            case "DESCRIPTION":
                $description .= $data;
                break;

            case "LINK":
                $link .= $data;
                break;

            case "PUBDATE":
                $date .= $data;
                break;

            case "AUTHOR":
                $author .= $data;
                break;
        }
    }
}

function begin_element($parser, $name) {
    global $is_item, $tag;
    if ($is_item) {
        $tag = $name;
    } else if ($name == "ITEM") {
        $is_item = true;
    }
}

function end_element($parser, $name) {
    global $is_item, $title, $description, $link, $date, $author, $rss2_output;
    if ($name == "ITEM") {
        $rss2_output .= "<dt><strong><a href='" . trim($link) . "'>" . htmlspecialchars(trim($title)) . "</a></strong> - " . htmlspecialchars(trim($date)) . " by <em>" . htmlspecialchars(trim($author)) . "</em></dt><dd>" . htmlspecialchars(trim($description)) . "</dd>";
        $title = "";
        $description = "";
        $link = "";
        $date = "";
        $author = "";
        $is_item = false;
    }
}

$parser = xml_parser_create();

xml_set_element_handler($parser, "begin_element", "end_element");
xml_set_character_data_handler($parser, "character_data");
$fp = fopen($rss2_file, "r");

while ($data = fread($fp, 4096)) {
    xml_parse($parser, $data, feof($fp));
}

fclose($fp);

xml_parser_free($parser);

echo "Latest Announcements:";
echo $rss2_output;
?>
```

index.php:

```
include 'rss.php';

echo $rss->title;

?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you were trying is used for accessing variables stored in classes. But that's not the case here so do it this way:

```
<?php
    include 'rss.php';
    echo $title;
?>
```

Comment: My problem with that is that the variables are initialized but they're not run through the methods so there's no data for them. Thanks for that though, I knew it was something small.

Comment: Would you be able to tell me how to make the rss file process before I echo the variable? I'll mark it if you're able to help. If not I'll mark it anyways, but yeah. :)

Comment: The file you're including will always be executed before it echos $title